# Compiling GWT to another Web-application

Tags: spring, gwt

I'm really new to gwt,

I'm tasked to compile the gwt project into JS files and add the GWT Servlets and Javascript files inside another Java web-application (spring).

other than the js file generated by gwt I've also copied the server folder from the gwt project to the other project. also added the service servlet to web.xml

the client side is working fine.

I want to know usually what other configurations I have to set to make this work?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT:

servlet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>applicationReportService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.project.reports.gwt.server.service.rpc.applicationReportServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>applicationReportService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/reports/applicationReportService.svc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what are you using for communication between server and client (JSON, GWT RPC) ?

Answer (score 2):

at runtime gwt depends un the gwt-user.jar and the gwt-servlet.jar. If you add them to your classpath as well as your servlets you should be fine

Comment: I added the two jar files to my classpath. now I'm getting this error:
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory ROOT
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
 at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1281)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1280)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)

Comment: seems like you are missing servlet api on your classpath

Comment: Well I had a problem with my database urls. I fixed that. But the servlet request mapping I'm assuming is not working. Because the response I get is HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. and the error message I'm getting is: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 please see my servlet mapping above in the question.